# Подписка на новости

Tags: php

Как сделать подписку на новости со своего сайта? Чтобы юзер мог получать на мыло новости с моего сайта. В сторону крона смотреть?

Answer (score 2):

Разбейте задачу на такие части:

- форму добавления e-mail пользователя в базу. Способы бывают разные, но главное явные.
- создайте способ создания данных для письма - к примеру скрипт будет собирать новости по какому то фильтру (дата, ручной выбор).
- формируя письмо для пользователя, не забудьте добавить ссылку на отписку (какими не были бы важными Ваши новости, пользователь иногда все же хочет отписаться и это его право).
- Собственно рассылку можно делать как кроном (в этом случае лучше разбить на части и отправлять кусками - это и сервер разгрузит, и провайдеры спасибо скажут). Можно и готовые скрипты для этого найти и дошлифовать(к [примеру](http://smartpost.ru/). Но есть готовые решение, к примеру http://mailchimp.com/, где вроде есть бесплатные планы.

Все ссылки в ответе найдены случайно гуглом.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если хотите временнýю рассылку - тогда действительно крон. Но разница между ними лишь в том, что в зависимости от того, как Ваше детище построено, Вам придётся использовать пул с новостями.

Если рассылка производится при добавлении новости, то тут всё просто - формируем и отправляем письмо.

Если рассылка производится в определённое время, то тут тоже несложно - формируется пул с новостями, необходимыми к отправке, далее вызовом крона из пула формируется либо 1 целиковое сообщение, либо же несколько (:-/), и так же отправляются.